# Ubuntu 13, TeXLIve and home made package

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I would like to install an homemade package ? With MacTeX, I put my package in `texmf-local` and then simply use `texhash`.

Under Ubuntu, I have to use the plain path `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/texhash`. This is a little boring.

Have you a way to avoid the use of the long plain path ?

Comment: You're probably using `sudo` in front of the command, aren't you?

Comment: Yes I forget to say that. I update my question now.

Comment: Add a file to `/etc/profile.d` which includes `[ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux" ] && export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}"`? (I don't use Ubuntu - I do this on Fedora.)

Comment: This does not work for me...

Comment: maybe using an alias like `alias mytexhash='sudo /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/texhash'`? You have to place that into your .bashrc file or the equivalent file where ubuntu stores bash config. Then you can just type `mytexhash` and it will call the long path automatically

Comment: This does not work...

Comment: have you sourced the .bahsrc file after adding the new alias?

Comment: I put mine in `/home/cmhughes/texmf/tex/latex/`

Comment: "have you sourced the .bahsrc file ?" How can I do that ?

Comment: (Will delete this comment.) Follow the advice @cmhughes and use `~/texmf/tex/latex`. It is, really, the best place to put personal `.sty` (etc.) files.  Note, however, that some files should be put in other locations.  A `.bib` file, e.g., should go in `~/texmf/bibtex/bib` while a `.bst` would go in `~/texmf/bibtex/bst`.  The structure of `~/texmf`, which you need to create yourself, should mimic the structure of your system tree.

Comment: This question seems like it is a duplicate of [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)... please confirm

Comment: While I agree with @cmhughes about where you should put custom packages (excepting font packages but you are unlikely to make those), you still need to sort out the problem with `PATH` in order to use the system effectively. If the problem only occurs when you use `sudo` is is somewhat contained (though may still cause issues sometime) but you should definitely ensure it is correct for your user. What does `echo $PATH` give?

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for your advice about the directory.

Comment: @cfr This gives the following path `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/cbal/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/texlive/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` where.

Comment: @projetmbc You should be all set then ;).